# How to get a component inside the Try catch block. ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I want to get the component from another file to the try-catch block. So for the example i created the component in one file

```
const Example = () => {
return (
<div>
<h2>this is a test</h2>
</div>
);
}

export default Example.
```

And in the App.js file i have a try-catch block but when i import new component to the catch it is not shown. But if a call the same component in the return statement it is shown. so for example

import Example from "./filename"

```
function App() {

  function clickFail() {
      
    try {
      console.log(window.device.version)
    } catch (e) {
    < Example /> 
  }
  }
}

return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={clickFail}>failed</button>
//if a call it from here it is shown.
  //    < Example />
    </div>
  );

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

The component must be part of the JSX either through a variable or through conditional rendering. Here's 2 ways you can achieve this.

With direct component reference in the state:

```
function App() {
  const [caughtComponent, setCaughtComponent] = useState(null);

  function clickFail() {
    try {
      console.log(window.device.version);
    } catch (e) {
      setCaughtComponent(() => <Example />);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={clickFail}>failed</button>
      {caughtComponent}
    </div>
  );
}
```

With a boolean that determines whether or not to render the component:

```
function App() {
  const [caughtError, setCaughtError] = useState(false);

  function clickFail() {
    try {
      console.log(window.device.version);
    } catch (e) {
      setCaughtError(true);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={clickFail}>failed</button>
      {caughtError && <Example />}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer But unfortunately I cannot edit and put anything in the return statement as you showed in your example inside the {} as in the real app I am working in the someones code and I am only allowed to call my component and not edit the file. So I am thinking on how can I call the component without touching the return statement

Comment: This is a really strange requirement. I can't think of anything off the top of my head that is guaranteed to work. A hackier idea that came to mind is to use `document.querySelector()` inside the `catch` statement and manually add the html as a string, but even this would require for you to add a `ref/class/id` (preferably ref) to the parent component and is overall a pretty bad way to do it. I suggest simply finding a way to edit the parent component as this is the cleanest solution and I'm confident all other solutions (if any) will result in code that is much harder to maintain.

Comment: Thanks for your helpi made simple example but in reality I am just adding my component to the other component in the other file. This file only has bunch or fetch requests with async try catch statements. And I need to add my component inside this catch statement. So this filewhere I add my component it does not have a return statement

Comment: This makes more sense. In that case you might look into global state management solutions like Redux and handle it from there or maybe transform  the file with the fetch requests into a React component?

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the file is reacts already

Answer (score 0):

When you create a functional component in React, only what is returned from the component will be displayed. In your example, there is actually no return statement inside of the `App()` component. You do trigger a `clickFail` call when the button is clicked, but the return from that function does not affect the app component. Also, your return statement for `App` is outside of the last bracket.

I am confused by your use case but regardless, if I understand correctly you are trying to display a component only when an error occurs. I think the best way to do this is with React `useState()` and conditional rendering. Here is how you could refactor to achieve the desired result:

```
const Example = () => {
  return ( 
  <div>
    <h2> this is a test </h2>
  </div>
  );
}

const App = () => {
  const [clickFailed, setClickFailed] = useState(false);

  const clickFail = () => {
    try {
      console.log(window.device.version)
    } catch () { 
      setClickFailed(true);
    }
  }

  return ( 
    <div>
      <button onClick={clickFail}>failed</button>
      {clickFailed ? <Example /> : null}
    </div>
  );

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer But unfortunately I cannot edit and put anything in the return statement as you showed in your example inside the {} as in the real app I am working in the someones code and I am only allowed to call my component and not edit the file. So I am thinking on how can I call the component without touching the return statement